# Is Starship Catan similar enough to be considered a two-player adaptation of Starfarers of Catan?

Tags: starfarers-of-catan

I've played Starfarers of Catan<sup>([BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1897/starfarers-of-catan)|[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfarers_of_Catan))</sup> once and loved it. Usually, I only have one other to play board games with. I'd like to know how similar Starship Catan<sup>([BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2338/starship-catan)|[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Catan))</sup> is so I can decide whether it's worth the purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has some similar ideas (e.g. your ship gets new abilities as you build it up), but it's really a totally different game.  And, I think, a better one.

Comment: Thank you! Could you, perhaps, go into a little more detail?

Comment: It's just a very different game.  Instead of a board that you explore, there are stacks of cards representing different sectors; the cards contain planets that you can trade at, enemies to fight, etc.  You choose a pile to explore, and then your sensors determine how many cards you can look at before you draw, and your engines determine how many cards you draw.  (This game was clearly a big influence on Galaxy Trucker.)  You still collect resources and use them to buy upgrades and the like.  I haven't played it in years, but I played it a lot when I first got it.  It's fun.

Comment: thanks. I'd really appreciate it if you'd integrate that comment into your answer.